# PLS00103: Encountered the symbol "I" when expecting one of the following

Tags: plsql

Dears,
I want to make a function to cleanse my phone numbers,
I wrote below function, but I faced with this error:

```
Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "I" when expecting one of the following:  
( Line: 15 Text: IF SUBSTR(O_NUM,1,3) IN I.E_CODE
```

[image]

Comment: Please post the code not as the picture but as text.

Comment: Did my answer fix the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code refers to `I.E_CODE`, but that's within a context in which `I` is a simple numeric variable:

```
FOR I IN NUM

   ... I.E_CODE ...

END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 0):

`IN` operator syntax is not correct. It should be

```
IF SUBSTR(O_NUM,1,3) IN(I.E_CODE)
```

Comment: you need to accept the answer, if your problem solved

Answer (score 0):

You better change to use `=` instead of `IN` for 1 value:

```
IF SUBSTR(O_NUM,1,3) = I.E_CODE
```

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect syntax. It should be:

```
FOR I IN NUM 
   if I.E_CODE = SUBSTR(O_NUM,1,3)    then
   end if; 
END LOOP;
```